Python Pandas - Finding values specific based in a CSV file
So i have a data frame looking like this CSV File
`LoginTime                         StudentName
2024-03-24 08:13:13+0000          James
2024-03-04 08:13:13+0000          James
2024-02-14 08:13:13+0000          Ryan
2024-03-01 08:13:13+0000          Steven
2024-02-09 08:13:13+0000          Lou
2024-03-25 08:13:13+0000          Haily
2024-03-07 08:13:13+0000          Haily
2024-01-10 08:13:13+0000          Steven
2024-03-31 08:13:13+0000          Lou
2024-03-28 08:13:13+0000          Steven
2024-01-19 08:13:13+0000          Steven
2024-03-16 08:13:13+0000          Ryan
2024-04-11 08:13:13+0000          Steven
2024-01-18 08:13:13+0000          Haily
2024-02-20 08:13:13+0000          Ryan`

And im trying to make it look like this Where for each StudentName has the most recent date
`LoginTime                         StudentName
2024-03-24 08:13:13+0000          James
2024-03-25 08:13:13+0000          Haily
2024-03-31 08:13:13+0000          Lou
2024-03-16 08:13:13+0000          Ryan
2024-04-11 08:13:13+0000          Steven`


And what have you tried?  Grouping and "max" will help you here.

@Tim idxmax actually ;)

Thanks guys, apologies for the simple question im new here xD
